# How to change the url text and not the actual page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page on my local server say `http://172.16.2.6:8005/abc.html`, and i want the testers to see that in a browser by some other url like `http://tesing.com/abc.html`. 
How to go about it?

Comment: Some context would be helpful to answer. Why you want to do that? If its testers, you should have separate environment for them. no?

Comment: You need a [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) on your network edge to proxy requests to and from your internal server.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I will go through the links.

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup `virtual hosting` in your server . i know for a fact that you can do this in Apache but not sure for IIS

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

and you need to setup your local dns server too
in windows go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and open it with a test editor and add a line to it like :

172.16.2.6:8005 tesing

and for the abc.com part you need to setup url rewriting

Comment: Thnk you @Exlord I will try dis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in javascript preferably on page load

```
window.location="http://tesing.com" + window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this is not helping me as dis redirects to `http://tesing.com + window.location.pathname`.